# Excel VBA Print multiple named range in seperate page of PDF

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, named

I have list of named ranges and each range I set it to suit single page. I use following code to export into PDF, where It get merged together into single page.

```
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim rs As Range

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set rs = wbBook.Names(1).RefersToRange
For i = 2 To wbBook.Names.Count
   Set rs = Union(rs, wbBook.Names(i).RefersToRange)
Next

rs.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath, , , False
```

But below code works for me, when I enter range name manually. Whereas my named range are dynamic. I think, above code needs some modification to work. Will anyone assist me to get this done?

```
Set rs = wbBook.Range("Page_1,Page_2,Page_3")
rs.Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath, , , False
```

Proposed solution still give one page. I provided below the page setup, Is something wrong with page setup ?

```
With Sheet1.PageSetup
.PrintArea = Range(Cells(iBeginRow, 1), Cells(iRow + 2, 5)).Address
.CenterHorizontally = True
.CenterVertically = True
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
.PrintQuality = 600
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
```

Then I dynamically name the range

```
Sheet1.Range(Cells(iBeginRow, 1), Cells(iRow + 2, 5)).Select
Selection.Name = "Page_" & PageNum
```

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: Sorry, My question was not clear. it was not an error. I wanted to keep the page set up of each named range intact while exporting; hence each named range data reflect in each page. I was able to do that when I enter named range manually. I want to keep original page setting of each named range in "rs" and export in first set of code.

Comment: Are you working with contiguous range in different sheets?

Comment: I am working with contiguous range in same sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below UDF worked for me (I had it in a module):

```
Sub ExportRangeToPDF(ByVal WSName As String)

    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim strPath As String: strPath = "C:\temp\Temp\"
    Dim intCount As Integer

    For intCount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

        If InStr(1, LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Names(intCount).RefersToRange.Name.Name), LCase(WSName)) > 0 Then

            If oRng Is Nothing Then
                Set oRng = Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(intCount).RefersToRange.Name.Name)
            Else
                Set oRng = Union(oRng, Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(intCount).RefersToRange.Name.Name))
            End If

        End If

    Next

    oRng.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath & "test.pdf", , , False

    Set oRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

**NOTE**: I had some 'solver' and 'filterdatabase' ranges in the workbook I was working on so had to add some validation for those before it worked. If you have any such ranges in your workbook, you might have to do the same

Comment: Proposed solution still give one page(Three named range data merged together) in single PDF file, whereas my need is three page output (for each named range) in single PDF file. I edited the question with page set up of each named range, Is something wrong with page setup ?   Note: I was able to do when passed the all the named range manually.

Comment: That's bizarre cos I got a PDF file with 3 pages (1 for each range). Do the ranges on your sheet overlap?

Comment: No, will you check my current page settings, which I gave in the question now?

Comment: I don't think page setup would affect named ranges (I could be wrong though). Any chance you can provide a snapshot of your worksheet and highlight the ranges?

Comment: It worked for me. What went wrong initially was, I didn't give any space (Blank Row) between first Named Range to other named range. That was the reason. Its working. Thank you!

Comment: I tried the same method to export into word; however each named range is not coming in different page of workbook. How can we get that done?. I tried to modify the code with different method. its failed.

Comment: I would suggest to start a new question as that's different problem. Let me know once you have and I'll try to help

Comment: I posted another question, Will you look into that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003210/excel-vba-copy-pasting-each-named-range-to-word

Comment: Yeah no worries. Bit busy at work at the moment but will have a look and post my reply on that question