# Excel VBA copy pasting each named range to word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, named-ranges

I have dynamic named range of cell. I need to paste each named range in one page of  word and move to next page for next named range. I tried copule of code, I am unable to do.Each named range data is overlapping  each other. Can anyone  help me, please.

```
Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set rs = wbBook.Names(1).RefersToRange

For i = 2 To wbBook.Names.Count
    Set rs = Union(rs, wbBook.Names(i).RefersToRange)
Next

rs.Copy

With wd.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .PasteSpecial False, False, True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to copy each range onto different pages so I'm not sure why you're using a union.  Here is a quick example of copying each named range 'name' onto a new sheet in a word document.  Note: I created a new doc for simplicity.

**Edit** - I added copy/paste functionality of data to the end.  Formatting and such depends on what you have or want.

```
Sub main()
    'Create new word document
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add()

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim rtarget As Word.Range
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Loop Through names
    For intCounter = 1 To wbBook.Names.Count
       Debug.Print wbBook.Names(intCounter)

       With objDoc
            Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)

            'Insert page break if not first page
            If intCounter > 1 Then rtarget.insertbreak Type:=wdPageBreak

            'Write name to new page of word document
            rtarget.Text = wbBook.Names(intCounter).Name & vbCr

            'Copy data from named range
            Range(wbBook.Names(intCounter)).Copy
            Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
            rtarget.Paste
       End With
    Next intCounter
End Sub
```

**Excel**

[image]

**Resulting Word Document**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Its not showing the data, instead shows worksheet range on each page.( =GenForm!$A$1:$E$22, =GenForm!$A$24:$E$29, etc....). Any other reason for this ?

Comment: See Edit - I added a simple copy/paste of the data.  It wasn't clear from your code that you wanted anything other than the range so I left that out originally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution out there (as I don't normally play with Word VBA) but I have tried this and it does seems to work:

```
Sub AddNamedRangesToWordDoc()

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oSelection As Object

    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    oWord.Visible = True

    For intCount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

        Set oRng = Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(intCount).RefersToRange.Name.Name)
        oRng.Copy

        oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteSpecial , , 0
        Set oSelection = oWord.Selection
        oSelection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)

    Next

    Set oSelection = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

**NOTE**: I am creating a new word application. You might have to check if word is already open and how you want to deal with an existing word doc. Also, I'm not creating the word object. I have `Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library` referenced in the project as I prefer to work with built in libraries. Also, function presumes that you only have 1 worksheet and all your ranges are in that worksheet